# How to Route directions from my location to specific place Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I've been read this Article about routes and stuff but here just show how to route by static Latitude and Longetude, i want route from my Location at Static location

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn818495.aspx) and [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn818495.aspx) Which is almost the same thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `bingmaps:?rtp=` but provide only the target coordinates, not the start ones. I use this code

```
var uri = "bingmaps:?rtp=~pos." + Detail.GeneralInfo.GpsCoordinates.GpsX.ToString().Replace(",", ".") + "_" + Detail.GeneralInfo.GpsCoordinates.GpsY.ToString().Replace(",", ".");
Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(uri));
```

Comment: As you can see in this second post he use BasicGeoposition and set the Latitude and Longitude, did you know some way to "Convert" Geolocator in my current location the latitude and longitude, so i can put thhis values insite of BasicGeopositon?